# Can i use master-slave replication on a cluster?

Tags: mariadb, cluster-computing, replication, zabbix, master-slave

I'm using MariaDB 5.5.60 on both zabbix-servers which have a clustering solution between them for zabbix-server service.

Can I use master-slave solution for a cluster?
If I have node1 and node2, and they both have MariaDB on them,
node1 is the master and node2 is the slave.

If node1 is down, can the slave keep the new information written to the database? or I need to make some sync to make slave master and vice versa?

Is there such a solution of master-slave or do I have a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

"Master-Slave" involves continually updating the Slave from the Master.  If the Master crashes, there is a small chance of something not having made it to the Slave, but otherwise, the Slave is 'always' identical to the Master.

"Failover" mostly involves redirecting traffic to the Slave and making it writable.

Then there is the hassle of setting up a new Slave to the new Master, etc.

But...  You have added confusion to the question by using the word "cluster".  That is probably referring to another replication technology that is more robust.  Does it also say "Galera" or "Group Replication" or "Innodb Cluster"?  Probably not, since it is the rather old (5.5).

Please study what Zabbix provides (I don't know what it does.) and study "Replication" in MySQL/MariaDB documentations.